# How violent are sand storms on Mars?

Tags: mars

In a future manned Mars mission, how bad a sand storm going to affect a mission? What are the measures taken to prevent damage from these sand storms?

Comment: Good question, but it's been covered, try a search for 'mars storm' in the search box at top right. Although the aspect of what measures are planned i don't see covered, so on that grounds it could be considered a follow up question.

Comment: There is an answer which covered couple of measures that might take to prevent.But i don't know if it covered all the measures.BTW Is there special case like follow up question?

Comment: Its been two years there might be some update on the solution for issues

Comment: There's no formal follow-up system, no. The thing is to edit the question so it focuses on things not covered before.